# Get empty prediction with Facebook Prophet

Tags: deep-learning, facebook-prophet

Following the basic steps to create Prophet model and forecast

```
m = Prophet(daily_seasonality=True)
m.fit(data)
forecast = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=2)
forecast.tail().T
```

the result is as following (no yhat value ??)

[image]

The data passed in to fit the model has two columns (date and value).
Not sure what I have missed out here.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it works by creating a new dataframe:

```
df_p = pd.DataFrame({'ds': d.index, 'y': d.values})
```

Comment: Yes, with Prophet you need a template in order to get the prediction: your data frame has to contain at least 'ds' and 'y' as columns ('ds' cannot be only at the index level), and all the exogenous variables you want to use for your predictions.